# Django Allauth - allow to sign up again if email is unverified

Tags: django, django-allauth

Suppose, user A tries to sign up with an email not of their own (user's B email). He fails to verify it and hence fails to sign in. Some time later user B encounters the site and tries to sign up, but they fail as well with a message "A user is already registered with this e-mail address." From what I see in admin site, it is true, the user instance is actually created, even though the email is unverified. Is there a way to easily allow user B to sign up (i.e. overwrite the unverified user instance)? Or what is the standard way of dealing with this situation?

Comment: Well, In the end decided to simply customize signup form error message to something like: '...If you believe this is a mistake or simply don't remember your password then go to Login page and follow 'Forgot Password' button.' Which I guess is acceptable, since user A didn't even have a chance to enter the account (and therefore to do nasty things on user's B behalf) and all user B needs to do is to claim a new password.

Answer (score 1):

That user will always be in the database in an "unverified" state unless you delete it. One option would be to run a cron job daily or weekly that deletes users that are unverified for over a certain amount of time.

Comment: seems a bit crude. Why set up a whole daily job when you could just allow to overwrite unverified accounts? And what if user's A unjustified email usage and user's B attempt to sign up happen on the same day? Or user A is just some troll that will do this daily to spite user B?